# Why there is only one thread can actually started in @PostConstruct method?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
@Component
class Type
{
    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstructor() {

        Runnable threadAlpha = () -> {
            while (true) {
                workWithSomething();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 60);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        Runnable threadBeta = () -> {
            while (true) {
                workWithOtherthing();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 3);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        threadBeta.run();
        threadAlpha.run();
    }
}
```

With spring-framework, I am struggling with this piece of code, the problem is only one thread can actually started which call `run()` first, the other one seems freezing, If I switch the location to be like:

```
        threadAlpha.run();
        threadBeta.run();
```

Then threadBeta never started, why something happen like that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring. You can simulate this in the simple standalone program as well.

Comment: @fiveelements, ok so we can remove spring and spring-boot tags?

Comment: I mentioned that for simulation purpose only. It has no relevance with spring. The behavior you are seeing due to the fact `Runnable#run()` executes in the current thread and does not start a new thread. Please see my answer in the answer section where I have modified your code slightly to use Thread and you may run it yourself.

Comment: You're not starting a threads, just creating runnable objects and execute them in the caller thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not creating threads. Instead of that you're creating `Runnable` instances and then running their `run` method.

Instead do this:

```java
new Thread(threadAlpha).start();
new Thread(threadBeta).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Runnable run() executes in the current thread and hence the behavior. If you want to run in two separate threads use `Thread` and call `start` on those:

```
public class SpringMultipleThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringMultipleThreads().postConstructor();
    }
    private void postConstructor() {

        Thread threadAlpha = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("1");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 3);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        });
        Thread threadBeta = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("2");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 3);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        });
        threadBeta.start();
        threadAlpha.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `threadAlpha.run()` and `threadBeta.run()` you are executing it in the current thread. For simple execution in new thread you can use:

```java
Thread t1 = new Thread(threadAlpha);
t1.start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(threadBeta);
t2.start();
```

[SimpleThreads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html) tutorial from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling **threadBeta.run()** or **threadAlpha.run()** you are calling a method which has an infinite loop. You are not creating a thread. That's why **threadAlpha.run()** isn't executing even as **threadBeta.run()** is in an infinite loop. Instead you can do this:

```
new Thread(threadBeta).start();
new Thread(threadAlpha).start();
```